# How to adapt my JavaScript to work with multiple rows and different value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `span` that works to display a currency symbol at the start of a price input box that changes based on what currency is selected in a dropdown box. These work by calling `notEmpty()` with an `onChange` event.

My code was:

```
function notEmpty(){
    var e = document.getElementById("currencysel");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var strUser2 = "&nbsp;" + strUser;
    document.getElementById('currencysym').innerHTML = strUser2;
}

notEmpty()
document.getElementById("currencysel").onchange = notEmpty;
```

I had to add the `&nbsp;` to properly align the symbol in the price text box.

This worked perfectly until I made two changes, I no longer use the actual currency symbol (£, $, €) as the value because MySQL does not like the £ symbol, I now use GBP, USD and EUR. The second change is with each row, I load a form that includes both the `currencysel` dropdown and the `currencysym` span. Now fixing this is easy, I can just append the row ID to the end of the `currencysel` and `currencysym` IDs, so an example row may have `currencysel6` and `currencysym6`, but how do I get the JavaScript to still recognize these despite the numbers on the end?

For the first issue, I tried:

```
function notEmpty(){
    var e = document.getElementById('currencysel');
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (strUser = 'GBP'){
        strUser2 = '&nbsp;£'
    } else if (strUser = "USD"){
        strUser2 = '&nbsp;$'
    } else if (strUser = "EUR"){
        strUser2 = '&nbsp;€'
    }
    document.getElementById('currencysym').innerHTML = strUser2;
}
```

But this didn't work.

The second issue I didn't have a single clue, which is where I'm hoping to receive your assistance.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66co5kfo/

Comment: How is your markup? Is it a `table`?

Comment: For the form, yes, a table, which is loaded in a modal if that is any help?

Comment: Can you provide us a jsfiddle to test your code?

Comment: I have now added the fiddle @Logar314159 that is the code working with the Dropdown values being the symbols (£, $, €), and not the currency codes (GBP, USD, EUR). I also need to make it so I can have several of these forms on the page and the JavaScript Code can discern between them. If that makes sense?

Comment: you could use the pound euro and dollar sign but use the html codes: &pound; &euro; &dollar; as for discerning between the forms, give them unique ids then you should be fine.

Comment: @Puzzle84 giving them unique IDs when the JavaScript is looking for an exact ID wouldn't work, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is access the elements by class name instead of by ID. You'll just need to provide a common class name on all the relevant `select` elements so you can access them. (And do the same thing for the corresponding `span` elements.

Then instead of `.getElementById()` you can use `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` along with CSS selectors (such as `".className"` to get an element with a class of "className").

Check out the example code below to see how you can access and attach events to multiple different elements without knowing their IDs.

```js
// get all the containing elements by classname
var pickers = document.querySelectorAll(".currencyPicker");

// loop through all those containers
var i = pickers.length;
while (i--) {
  // this is an immediately executing function expresion which creates a closure
  // the closure allows the event listener to access the span and select elements
  (function(span, select) {
    // attach the change event to the select element  
    select.addEventListener("change", function() {
      notEmpty(span, select);
    });
  })(pickers[i].querySelector(".currencysym"), pickers[i].querySelector(".currencysel"));
}

function notEmpty(spanToUpdate, select) {
  switch(select.value){
      case "USD":
        spanToUpdate.innerHTML = "$";
        break;
      case "GBP":
        spanToUpdate.innerHTML = "£";
        break;
      case "EUR":
        spanToUpdate.innerHTML = "€";
        break;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="currencyPicker">
        <select class="currencysel">
          <options>
            <option value="USD">$</option>
            <option value="GBP">£</option>
            <option value="EUR">€</option>
          </options>
        </select>
        <span class="currencysym">$</span>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="currencyPicker">
        <select class="currencysel">
          <options>
            <option value="USD">$</option>
            <option value="GBP">£</option>
            <option value="EUR">€</option>
          </options>
        </select>
        <span class="currencysym">$</span>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="currencyPicker">
        <select class="currencysel">
          <options>
            <option value="USD">$</option>
            <option value="GBP">£</option>
            <option value="EUR">€</option>
          </options>
        </select>
        <span class="currencysym">$</span>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As I mentioned in the code comments, the following pattern is used to create an immediately executing function expression (IIFE), which is an advanced but handy JavaScript concept.

```
(function(){
    // code
})();
```

This is useful in a loop because you can pass parameters into the function expression to get snapshots of variable values, which you can then pass on to other functions (which might not execute right away, as in the case of event handlers) as needed.

```
originalVariable = arr[i];
(function(copiedVariable){
    // code that uses copiedVariable
})(originalVariable);
```

Comment: Hi @Thriggle, for this to work, do I have to have the currencysel before the currencysym? Also, I want the symbol to show up next to the price, rather than the currency code.

Comment: @radiocaf The order shouldn't matter, but notice that I did wrap up the `currencysel` and `currencysym` elements in a `div` with a class of `currencyPicker`. The code queries all the currencyPickers, then queries each of those results for the inner currencysel/currencysym elements.

Comment: @radiocaf I also updated the code with an example of a switch statement for handling the currency symbol/abbreviation swap.

Comment: thank you, it must be something I'm doing wrong, does the code rely on anything else? I only ask in case something to do with my layout is stopping it from running.

Comment: @radiocaf nope, this is all vanilla JavaScript. If you want to put the code you have so far in a jsfiddle, I can definitely take a look at it and see if anything stands out. Sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes.

Comment: I will get a JSFiddle up asap, I'll try and explain a little further: index.php includes list.php, which is the page that lists the rows, and for each row loaded with a while loop, an Edit button and modal is loaded with each row, which includes edit.php which is essentially just the form. I tried adding the currencyPicker class div to the edit.php and the javascript to the list.php so the script is only loaded once, this didn't work. What did work was adding the script to the edit.php but this is bad as the script is added once with every row. I hope that's easy to understand.

Comment: I finally got it to work, without having to add the script to the while loop so it gets repeated with every row. I found adding the script after the while loop works. I imagine having the script above the loop or in the header doesn't work because maybe the script starts before the PHP or server is processed and the rows are added? I am probably wrong, but that's the only explanation I can think of. Thanks Thriggle.

Answer (score 1):

I created a plunker for your solution. This code does not require any additional Javascript libraries, but does require bootstrap CSS. It can also be done with plain text if you did not want to use CSS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/V0GDRY?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Select a currency</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="currencyDropdown">
      <option value="glyphicon-gbp">£</option>
      <option value="glyphicon-usd">$</option>
      <option value="glpyhicon-euro">€</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Enter a Price</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-gbp" id="currencySymbol"></div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Price</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
 function changeCurrencyType (symbolClass) {
  var symbol = document.getElementById('currencySymbol');

  symbol.className = 'input-group-addon glyphicon ' + symbolClass;
}

(function () {
  var currencyDropdown = document.getElementById('currencyDropdown');  

  currencyDropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var symbolClass = currencyDropdown.options[currencyDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

    changeCurrencyType(symbolClass);
  }, false);
})();
```

Comment: If you need this in a table, I could provide the HTML, but the mechanics are the same.

Comment: If you have the option, you should use a declarative framework like Angular or Ember when developing. These frameworks make developing much easier, and less stateful in situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only problem is: `if (strUser = 'GBP')`, this should be: `if (strUser == 'GBP')` (must use double equals ==)

http://jsfiddle.net/ewLsoyvh/